# No arg Constructor in Spring negates Constructor based DI benefits

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As per definiton of Spring bean , POJO should have a no -arg constructor.
Considering the benefits of Constructor based DI wherein by looking at the constructor itself we come to know what are its dependencies,doesnt having a no arg constructor removes this advantage.

Answer (score 3):

### horses for courses

Constructor based dependency injection is more predictive and creates immutable , fully initialised objects. Setter based DI is for dependencies considered optional, but also allows further reconfiguration of the object at a later stage. Both are valid, both have trade-offs, and therefore both are widely used.

From [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-setter-injection) (see **Constructor-based or setter-based DI?** box):

> The Spring team generally advocates **constructor injection** as it enables one to implement application components as **immutable objects** and to ensure that required dependencies are not null. Furthermore constructor-injected components are always returned to client (calling) code in a fully initialized state. As a side note, a **large number of constructor arguments is a bad code smell**, implying that the class likely has too many responsibilities and should be refactored to better address proper separation of concerns.
>
> **Setter injection** should primarily only be used for **optional dependencies** that can be assigned reasonable default values within the class. Otherwise, **not-null checks must be performed everywhere** the code uses the dependency. One benefit of setter injection is that setter methods make objects of that class **amenable to reconfiguration or re-injection** later.

<sup>(highlights are mine)</sup>

Comment: it seems u didnt understand my point. The whole point of creating Constructor based injection as per my knowldge is that by looking at the class we should come to knw all the required dependencies.However if we are creating no-arg constr, there is still scope for ambiguity bcoz class can be  created without all its dependencies and if we dnt create default constr,spring throws BeanInstatantion exception(bcz it uses reflection i guess). so constructr based DI may nt serve the purpose it is supposed is my question ?

Comment: @darshankamat That POJO should have some constructor definition, either a no-arg constructor, or another parameter-based one, that could be autowired by Spring. See here: https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring